# Aligning Text / Icon Within Button

Tags: html, css, button, icons, alignment

I've tried many different things on the web and from SO and again can't seem to get this to work. First time I've been changing / styling my buttons and they're driving me mad! So I have a left floated button on the same line as my right floated button now. I'd like to see if I can have the icon to the left of the text on the left button and the right of the text on the right button. Like this:

<- Last Page //////////////////////////////////////////////// Next Page ->

```
<span align="right">
<ul class="actions">
<li id="leftbutton"><a href="tfn.html" class="button special icon fa-arrow-left">TFN</a></li>
<li id="rightbutton"><a href="medical-indemnity-and-insurance.html" class="button special icon fa-arrow-right">Indemnity & Insurance</a></li>
</ul>
</span>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6bpvdf5/)

For some reason on the above fiddle it doesn't seem to be showing the font awesome arrows?

Thank you so much!

S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert te font-awsome icons whit the `<i>` element:

```
<span align="right">
  <ul class="actions">
     <li id="leftbutton"><a href="tfn.html" class="button special icon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> TFN</a></li>
     <li id="rightbutton"><a href="medical-indemnity-and-insurance.html" class="button special icon ">Indemnity & Insurance <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n6bpvdf5/1/

Answer (score 1):

class will be `fa fa-arrow-right` not `icon fa-arrow-right`.

**Like** 
`<a href="tfn.html" class="button special fa fa-arrow-left">TFN</a>`

It's always best practice to use `<i>` tag when you use a font awesome icon

**Like**
`<a href="tfn.html" class="button special"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>TFN</a>`